multiple Instances of screen injected Flutter Bloc with OnGenerateRoute
I am working on a Flutter app using the Bloc pattern for state management, and I’m encountering an issue where multiple routes are being pushed onto the navigation stack despite having a single navigation trigger
I have implemented navigation logic inside a BlocListener, which listens to specific states of my AuthBloc to navigate the user to different screens. Here's a snippet of the BlocListener code
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final AppRouter appRouter = AppRouter();
  final initialRoute = await appRouter.getInitialRoute();

  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => LocaleCubit()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => AuthBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => OnboardingBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => HomeBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => SettingsBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => AddVehicleBloc()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => ProfileSettingsBloc()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(initialRoute: initialRoute, appRouter: appRouter),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialRoute;
  final AppRouter appRouter;

  const MyApp({Key? key, required this.initialRoute, required this.appRouter}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BlocBuilder<LocaleCubit, Locale>(
      builder: (context, locale) {
        return MaterialApp(
          locale: locale,
          supportedLocales: const [
            Locale('en', 'US'),
            Locale('ur', 'PK'),
          ],
          localizationsDelegates: const [
            S.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: AppColors.backgroundDarkWhite,
          ),
          initialRoute: initialRoute,
          onGenerateRoute: appRouter.onGenerateRoute,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


class AppRouter {


  static const String home = '/home';
  static const String onboarding1 = '/';
  static const String onboarding2 = '/onboarding2';
  static const String enableLocation = '/enableLocation';
  static const String signUpScreen = '/signUpScreen';
  static const String signInScreen = '/signInScreen';
  static const String otpScreen = '/otpScreen';
  static const String userDataInputScreen = '/userDataInputScreen';
  static const String myWallet = '/myWalletScreen';
  static const String mainWrapper = '/mainWrapper';
  static const String vehicleManagement = '/vehicleManagement';
  static const String addVehicle = '/addVehicle';
  static const String termsAndConditions = '/termsAndConditions';
  static const String documentsManagement = '/documentsManagement';
  static const String updateDocuments = '/updateDocuments';

  static const String profileSettingsScreen = '/profileSettingsScreen';
  static const String languageSettingsScreen = '/languageSettingsScreen';









  Future<String> getInitialRoute() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool isLoggedIn = prefs.getBool('isLoggedIn') ?? false;
    bool isFirstTime = prefs.getBool('isFirstTime') ?? true;

    if (isLoggedIn) {
      return mainWrapper;
    } else if (isFirstTime) {
      return onboarding1;
      return mainWrapper;
    } else {
      return signInScreen;
      return mainWrapper;
    }
  }

  Route<dynamic> onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case mainWrapper:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const MainWrapper());
      case home:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const HomeScreen());
      case onboarding1:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const OnBoardingScreen());
      case enableLocation:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const EnableLocationScreen());
      case onboarding2:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) =>  OnBoardingSecondScreen());
      case signUpScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SignUpScreen());
      case signInScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const SignInScreen());
      case otpScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) =>  OtpScreen());
      case userDataInputScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) =>  UserDataInputScreen());
      case myWallet:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const MyWalletScreen());
      case vehicleManagement:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const VehicleManagementScreen());
      case addVehicle:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) =>  AddVehiclePage());
      case termsAndConditions:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const TermsScreen());
      case documentsManagement:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const DocumentManagementScreen());
      case updateDocuments:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const UpdateDocumentScreen());
      case profileSettingsScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const ProfileSettingsScreen());
      case languageSettingsScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const LanguageSettingsPage());
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}')),
          ),
        );
    }
  }


  void dispose() {

  }
}




The problem occurs whenever I use blocs in my screen. Whenever the state changes, the same screen is injected multiple times.
For example, in the OTP screen, when I try to press the confirm button multiple times, the screen is added to the navigation stack repeatedly.
Here is the code for my OTP screen:
class OtpScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  OtpScreen({super.key});

  // Create separate controllers for each OTP input
  final List<TextEditingController> otpControllers = List.generate(4, (index) => TextEditingController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final authBloc = BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context);

    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundDarkWhite,
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_back_rounded,
                  color: AppColors.primaryColor,
                ),
              ),
              insertPadding(top: height * 0.12),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45.0),
                child: AppText.largeNormal('Phone Verification'),
              ),
              insertPadding(top: 14),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45.0),
                child: AppText.small('Enter your OTP code here'),
              ),
              insertPadding(top: 20),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: List.generate(4, (index) {
                    return SizedBox(
                      width: width * 0.16,  // Width for each OTP box
                      child: TextField(
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 36,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600
                        ),

                        controller: otpControllers[index],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        showCursor:false,

                        maxLength: 1,  // Limit to one character per field
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          hintText: '●',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xff242A37),
                            fontSize: 36,
                          ),
                          counterText: "",
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: AppColors.underLineGrey,
                              width: 4.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: AppColors.underLineGrey,
                              width: 4.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onChanged: (value) {

                          if (value.length == 1 && index < 3) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
                          }

                          if (value.isEmpty && index > 0) {
                            FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
              insertPadding(top: height * 0.10),
            
              BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                listener: (context, state) {
              
                  if (state.isOtpCodeValid && !state.isUserProfileDataFilled) {
              
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/userDataInputScreen');
                  } else if(state.isOtpCodeValid){
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/mainWrapper');
                   

                  }

                  else if (state.errorMessage != null) {
              


                    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(content: Text(state.errorMessage!)),
                    );
                  }
                },
                listenWhen: (previous, current) {
                  // Only listen if errorMessage or isOtpCodeValid has changed
                  return previous.errorMessage != current.errorMessage ||
                      previous.isOtpCodeValid != current.isOtpCodeValid;
                },
                child: BlocBuilder<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45.0),
                      child: PrimaryButton(
                        size: ButtonSize.small,
                        label: 'VERIFY NOW',
                        onTap: () {
                          String otpCode = otpControllers.map((controller) => controller.text).join();
                   
                          if(otpCode.length == 4){
                            context.read<AuthBloc>().add(AuthOtpSendCode(otpCode: otpCode));
                          }
                        },
                        isLoading: state.isLoading,
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _loginUser() async {
    // Logic for successful login

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool('isLoggedIn', true);
    prefs.setBool('isFirstTime', false);
  }

}

